# How do I Extend User Profile Correctly in django 1.11

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using the `django_rest framework` to build an API with `python3`+ `django 1.11`.

I have created two apps: one is the **accounts** app to handle `user profiles` and **hr** which contains `Employee` class:

In my **accounts** app I have two classes - `User` and `Bio` defined as below respectively:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    provider = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='rel_doc')


    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.last_name.upper(), self.first_name)
        return full_name.strip()


class Bio(models.Model):
    marital_status = models.ForeignKey(MaritalStatus, blank=True, null=True)
    employment = models.ForeignKey(Employment, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    id_type = models.ForeignKey(IdentificationType, null=True, blank=True)
    main_id_type_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    siblings = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    no_in_household = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ethnicity = models.ForeignKey(Ethnicity, null=True, blank=True)
    blood_type = models.ForeignKey(BloodType, null=True, blank=True)
    preferred_language = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.ManyToManyField(Sex)
    em_contact = models.ForeignKey(EmergencyContact, null=True, blank=True)
    em_c_relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have imported `Bio` class to **hr** app in `Employee` class as `OneToOneField`. The problem is that I can't get the first names and last names of users I created.

[image]
How do I inherit fields such as `gender`,`dob`,`user` to the `Employee` class in

Comment: are you using serializer?

Answer (score 0):

I imported:

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`

`from accounts.models import User`

Then:

`User = get_user_model()`

## Define Serializers

```
class BioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user= UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model= Bio
        fields= ['user','marital_status','id_type','main_id_type_no','birthday','preferred_language','phone_number','gender']



# Nest Bio With User seriializer
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: Define serializer fields here
    bio = BioSerializer(read_only=True)
    #user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        # fields = ['user','tax_id_number','account_number','joining_date','designation','department','gender','marital_status','id_type','birthday','ethnicity','preferred_language','phone_number','em_contact','address']
        fields = '__all__'
```

[image]